# Getting Warning: Session become too large.Will stop sending websocket data

Tags: reactjs, node.js, websocket, socket.io, google-compute-engine

Server is hosted on google-compute-engine. I am getting the warning on client side as "Session become too large.Will stop sending websocket data". How can I manage the web-socket(using socket.io) long session for more than a two hour, for real-time transcription(I am sending the audio blobs in real-time and getting back the transcription) using Nodejs and Reactjs, after 1hr of session socket connection is getting disconnected.

[image: Warning Image]

How can I check what's causing this issue and which optimization techniques I can use to manage the memory cache, my chrome tab is consuming around 1.5 GB of memory? In server's memory it would be storing the more than 60k characters in single web-socket session.

I have tried emitting heartbeat event after every 30 seconds to keep the session alive.